# Did Jodie Foster say all men over 30 are full-blown rapists?

Tags: celebrities

A [December 23, 2017 YourNewsWire.com article](http://yournewswire.com/jodie-foster-men-rapists/) claims:

> Actress Jodie Foster says she believes “every single man over 30” is a
>   full-blown rapist whether they admit it or not.

Is this true?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

No, this is a beat-up.

YourNewsWire, to their credit, provide direct links to their sources:

- A [USA Today interview](https://www.usatoday.com/story/life/movies/2017/12/20/jodie-foster-every-man-over-30-has-start-thinking-their-part-sexual-misconduct/970017001/):

  > Pretty much every man over 30 has to really look and start thinking about their part. And I guarantee, lots of it is unconscious. When you’ve been in a privileged position where you haven’t had to look at your part, you didn’t 100% understand you were in a bubble. It’s an interesting time for men.
- A [Breitbart report on the USA Today interview](http://www.breitbart.com/big-hollywood/2017/12/22/jodie-foster-every-man-part-sex-misconuduct/):

  > Actress Jodie Foster has claimed that “pretty much every man over 30” has to consider their part to play in the recent sexual harassment scandal that has engulfed Hollywood since the emergence of misconduct allegations against Harvey Weinstein.

From these sources we can see there is no mention of the word "rapist" - either metaphorically or literally (as "full-blown" would suggest). The topic of discussion is sexual harassment, not rape.

There is no suggestion that "every single man" is directly engaging in rape and/or sexual harassment.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are quoting breitbart here, as they add no relevant information and are not a reliable source anyways. We already have the original quote from USA Today. If you want to show how the far-right purposefully misrepresents that quote - so that it eventually ends up being the quote in question -, then the quote you are using doesn't really do that (in contrast to the headline, it's actually pretty accurate).

Comment: @tim: That wasn't my intention - I didn't mean to make implications about the politics of Breitbart. Breitbart was cited by YourNewsWire. I quoted them to show that they did NOT make the false claim (you need to read the whole Breitbart article to see that, not just the quote), so that the investigation could stop there. Had they made a claim that Foster said something else, I would need to follow up *their* sources.